# Azure B2C SAML Email Claim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have successfully setup Azure B2C using the local account start packs using B2C as the IDP, we've integrated with a partner and can access their application. How do we go about Passing the local IDP accounts 'email' attribute to the partner as a claim. They're getting first, last name and display name without issue but not receiving the email claim.

Similar issue to this: [Azure B2C SAML Custom Policy Assert Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716629/azure-b2c-saml-custom-policy-assert-email)

I've inserted this into the BaseFramework

```
<ClaimType Id="email">
  <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="email" />
    <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/email" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
  ...
</ClaimType>
```

And this Technical Profile

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

and then this in the SAML flow:

```
 <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignInWithCA" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="objectId" ExcludeAsClaim="true" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

But it's still not working

As above modified as per documentation

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t need to make any of these changes, except in the third snippet you needed to put this

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
```

This takes the signInNames.emailAddress and issues it as “email” into the token.

Currently you defined a claim called email, read a claim called signInNames.emailAddress, then try to issue a claim called email into the token, which will be null.